# Triggering multiple videos with video-js functionality

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

Playing multiple videos with video-js functionality is actually possible:

**[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/gulli/88obmhoc/5/)**

However when wrapping a trigger such as a button around the function which invokes `playVideo()`, the video-js functionality breaks from the second video on.

**[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/gulli/88obmhoc/7/)**

```
...
$('#start').click(function() {
    ...
});
... 
// The rest of the code in Fiddle 2 is similar to Fiddle 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a number to the `playVideo()` function as a parameter. In your examples they are set to 0.

Then turn

```
videojs(document.getElementsByClassName("video-js")[0], {}, function () {});
```

to

```
videojs(document.getElementsByClassName("video-js")[number], {}, function () {});
```

That´s it:

**Demo: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gulli/nv1frvn4/)**